# Offset(2nd) argument in lseek

Tags: c, linux, lseek

I run the below program. I expected it'll give error. But it run perfectly and gave output.

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int fd, retval;
    char wBuf[20] = "Be my friend", rBuf[20] = {0};

    fd = open("test.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666);
    write(fd, wBuf, strlen(wBuf));

    retval = lseek(fd, -3L, SEEK_END); //Observe 2nd argument
    if(retval < 0) {
            perror("lseek");
            exit(1);
    }

    read(fd, rBuf, 5);
    printf("%s\n", rBuf);
}
```

`lseek` also works for

```
lseek(fd, -3I, SEEK_END); //but didn't print anything
```

For other letters it's giving error like

```
error: invalid suffix "S" on integer constant
```

What is the meaning of `L` and `I` on lseek?

Comment: @unwind. I don't think they are related to number suffix. S for Short but gave me error

Comment: There is no suffix for short, you cannot end a number literal with an `S`, which is why you're getting the error when you try.

Comment: @unwind I tried with U and Got error

Answer (score 2):

`L` simply means that the constant will be treated as a `long` type rather than the default integer type.

`I` is not a standard C suffix so, unless your compiler has some sort of extension <sup>(a)</sup>, it shouldn't be valid. It *may* be that you're mistaken a lower-case `l` (which means the same as `L`) for the upper-case `I`, although I suspect in that case it would still seek, read and print, something you seem to indicate it doesn't.

In fact, the only way I can think of where you could use `I` in standard C and have it print nothing would be with something like:

```
#define I * 0
```

which would effectively turn the `lseek` argument into zero.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Such as gcc with its complex data types, as may be the case. The effect of passing one of those to `lseek` is likely to be dysfunctional at best.

Perhaps this is an attempt to seek to a specific character position within the file and then also seek at right angles to that position :-)

Comment: i know L for Long and U for Unsigned. I tried them. but Only L and I are working. S is for Short. but gave me error. I don't think they are not number suffixes

Comment: @SGG, there is no s suffix in standard C. And if u doesn't work, the implementation is broken.

Answer (score 0):

The L suffix on a literal number simply means the type of number is `long` instead of the default of `int`

```
123 //this is an int
123L //this is a long
```

The I suffix is a gcc extension for [complex/imaginary numbers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Complex.html#Complex).

```
123; //this is an int
123I; //this is a _Complex
```

In C, there are the following suffixes for integer constants (they are case insensitive)

- `l` for long,
- `ll` for long long.
- `u` for unsigned

And for floating point constants:

- `f` for float.
- `l` for long double

(and any extensions a particular compiler might support.)

Comment: S for Signed Short. But gave error.

Comment: @SGG There is no `S` suffix on numbers in C.